# on each document click I want to pass different value in debounceTime() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I am using debounceTime() of Rxjs. Which means It will subscribe after the miliseconds which I will pass to function.
So, I am calling debounceTime() on each document click by giving different value of time. 
1st time I give 1 min. to this function. Like - debounceTime(1*60*1000). This is okay.
2nd time when I give 2 min. to this function. Like - debounceTime(2*60*1000).
It is subscribing in 1 minute only (It should subscribe in 2 minute).

Below is my small code in angular6 component.
First time I called this function in ngOnInit() with 1 minute as a value.

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick($event) {
        this.timeoutMins = 2;
        this.updateTimer.next($event);
    }

this.clickOrKeyEvent = this.updateTimer.pipe(
            debounceTime(this.timeoutMins * 60 * 1000),
        )
            .subscribe(() => {
                console.log(this.timeoutMins);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your updateTime of type `Observable`? 
If it is a bare Observable you are creating a new Observable by subscribing and therefor by clicking your button after 10 seconds you should get a `2` logged to console at 60 seconds (OnInit), and at 130 seconds (Click).

You could look at [ReplaySubjects](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html) in case you want only one Observable to work in the background.

I hope I understood you correctly. If this did not help please provide a complete code example and explain the exact behaviour you are looking for.